# При попытке добавления папки в архив - ошибка The path is too long

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetzip

Использую .Net Framework 4.0; VS 2015; Ionic.Zip.Reduced (DotNetZip.Reduced) v1.9.1.8. При попытке добавления папки в архив получаю исключение с текстом:

> The path is too long

Пример кода:

```
using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilePath))
{
  zipFile.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
  zipFile.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
  zipFile.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  zipFile.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;

  var dirPath = @"C:\AAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\";
  zipFile.AddDirectory(dirPath);  <-Exception
  zipFile.Save();
}
```

В папке расположен файл с именем:
`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.zip`

В результате выполнения, ошибка:

> The path is too long

Переписал на пофайловое добавление в архив (с использованием отоносительного пути):

```
using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilePath))
{
  zipFile.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
  zipFile.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
  zipFile.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  zipFile.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;

  var dirPath = @"C:\AAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAA\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\";
  Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath);
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();

  foreach (var fullFilePath in files)
  {
     var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath);
     var relatedPath = fullFilePath.Substring(0, fullFilePath.LastIndexOf(fileName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Replace(zipDir, "");
     var relatedFilePath = Path.Combine(relatedPath, fileName);

     zipFile.AddFile(relatedFilePath);   <-Exception
  }
  zipFile.Save();
}
```

Ошибка та же:

> The path is too long

Пробовал вызвать метод`Path.GetDirectoryName()`, но он тоже возвращает ошибку:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Нашел много решений но заставить работать так и не получилось (из за специфики приложения на новую версию Framework'а перейти не могу).

- Использовать Framework 4.6.2. Установить [опцию](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/09/new-net-path-handling-sneak-peek/) `UseLegacyPathHandling=false` в `App.Config` или даже `Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false; Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false`
- Что то упоминается о груповой политике и включении опции Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > [Enable NTFS long paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#namespaces), или включить опцию с помощью манифеста `<ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>`
- Использовать префикс `\\?\` [в пути](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath) (Я так понял что тоже для новой версии Framework'а)
- Преобразовать путь к файлу в формат 8.3 с помощью функции [GetShortPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)…. (ошибка осталась)

Может кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Буду рад любому совету.

Comment: возможно перед добавлением в архив стоит скопировать файлы во временную директорию с более коротким path, а уже из нее добавлять в архив?

Comment: А зачем в принципе нужен такой длинный путь?

Comment: @sp7 Такая длина пути уже существует, я пытаюсь просто заархивировать данные.

Comment: @tCode Как вариант, только если таких файлов много это будет немножко накладно.

Comment: @androschuk DotNetZip не поддерживает длинные пути. Меняйте библиотеку - попробуйте https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/, вдруг она вытянет длинный путь.

Comment: @androschuk, папка-то временная, после создания архива сделать очистку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это проблема самой операционной системы, её пофиксили буквально на днях для windows 10 в очередном апдейте.

Почитайте вот эту статью на хабре: https://habrahabr.ru/post/307186/ - в принципе, там хорошо резюмированы те варианты, которые вы упоминали.

`Использовать Framework 4.6.2` - этот вариант не очень хорош. Не у всех есть такой фреймворк, да и что делать на других операционках?

`Использовать префикс \\?\` - будут те же самые ошибки, если не включить поддержку длинных путей. Да, только новый фреймворк, увы.

Самый простой вариант -- выкидывайте пользователю сообщение о том, что операционная система не поддерживает такие длинные пути, пусть задумывается о переделке структуры каталогов и/или сокращает названия файлов.

Почему вы не хотите честно поймать исключение и честно его обработать? Даже если найдёте временную папку, где одно конкретное имя уместится -- завтра появится ещё на три символа длиннее и снова не хватит.